# Python sort dictionary by descending values and then by keys alphabetically

Tags: python, sorting

I have the following dictionary:

```
fruits = {
    "apple": 5,
    "Apple": 5,
    "orange": 5,
    "strawberry": 3,
    "blueberry": 1
}
```

I need to print out a list of the two keys with the highest values. Ties need to be broken alphabetically A-Z with capital letters taking precedence over lowercase ones. Running the following sorts by the counts, but doesn't break the ties:

```
popular_fruits = sorted(fruits, key=fruits.get, reverse=True)
print(popular_fruits[0:2])
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What's your output be like?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
popular_fruits = sorted(fruits, key=lambda x: (-fruits[x], x))
print(popular_fruits[0:2])
```

EDIT:

A negation before `fruits[x]` is used to reverse the decreasing numeric ordering 
and in case of a tie the order is determined by the second argument of the tuple (alphabetically).

One cannot simply use `sorted(fruits, key=lambda x: (fruits[x], x), reverse=True)` because it will reverse ordering for both tuple elements, but we need to do it for the first element only.

Comment: good answer, but can u explain how it works 'lambda x: (-fruits[x], x)'

Comment: @Roushan Do you understand how a list of tuples is sorted if you don't supply a key function?

Comment: may be not,but if u have any link or refernce then it will be gtt

Answer (score 4):

You can do secondary sorting by using a tuple. I used -1 * the value to reverse it. "Capitals first" is the default sorting order for Python.

**This is wrong even though it got some upvotes:**

```
popular_fruits = sorted(fruits, key = lambda x: (-1 * x[1], x[0]))

# ['Apple', 'apple']
```

It should be as taras posted:

```
popular_fruits = sorted(fruits, key = lambda x: (-fruits[x], x))
```

I was sorting by the first and second letter and happened to give the first two items in order correctly but is actually completely wrong. I'll keep this up if people think it is useful to see an error that you can make by confusing a `dict` for a list of lists/tuples.

Comment: Or just `(-x[1], x[0])`

Comment: I think I have an issue in my answer. Checking it now.

Comment: @RoadRunner Your version gave me a `bad operand type for unary -: 'str'` error which let me know my answer was completely wrong. I think it would have worked in a list of lists but not in a dict.